# How to receive jsonify variables on .js file from flask

Tags: javascript, python, json, ajax, flask

I would like to send a string from my Flask app to a .js file (not a script on HTML). I know I need to use an Ajax 'GET' Type but i am not sure on how to receive it on the .js file and console.log the data.

```
@app.route('/',methods =['GET','POST'])
def index():
    req = json.dumps(request.get_json())

    if request.method == 'POST':
        result = getString(req) #Function outputs a string
        print('Received')
        return jsonify(result)
    else:
        print('Not Received')

    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

.js file (Which needs help):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/",
    type: 'GET',
    data: ???, #What should i put here
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the following snippet implies that if the endpoint receives a GET request then nothing will be returned.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    result = getString(req) #Function outputs a string
    print('Received')
    return jsonify(result)
else:
    # This is what will get called on a GET request
    print('Not Received')
```

After you fix that, you don't need the `data` field on the ajax side at all unless you want to provide some query parameters.